# how to get browser properties using PHP?

Tags: php, browser, properties

There are many browsers, and some common features among all. How do we get those common properties of the browser using PHP.

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$browser = get_browser();
print_r($browser);
?>
```

this will give only the browser name and remaining properties?

Comment: Are there any properties you are looking for in particular?

Answer (score 0):

Following user defined function may work for you

```
function getBrowser() {

        $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        $bname = 'Unknown';
        $platform = 'Unknown';
        $version = "";

        //First get the platform?
        if (preg_match('/linux/i', $u_agent)) {
            $platform = 'linux';
        } elseif (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $u_agent)) {
            $platform = 'mac';
        } elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $u_agent)) {
            $platform = 'windows';
        }

        // Next get the name of the useragent yes seperately and for good reason
        if (preg_match('/MSIE/i', $u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i', $u_agent)) {
            $bname = 'Internet Explorer';
            $ub = "MSIE";
        } elseif (preg_match('/Firefox/i', $u_agent)) {
            $bname = 'Mozilla Firefox';
            $ub = "Firefox";
        } elseif (preg_match('/Chrome/i', $u_agent)) {
            $bname = 'Google Chrome';
            $ub = "Chrome";
        } elseif (preg_match('/Safari/i', $u_agent)) {
            $bname = 'Apple Safari';
            $ub = "Safari";
        } elseif (preg_match('/Opera/i', $u_agent)) {
            $bname = 'Opera';
            $ub = "Opera";
        } elseif (preg_match('/Netscape/i', $u_agent)) {
            $bname = 'Netscape';
            $ub = "Netscape";
        }

        // finally get the correct version number
        $known = array('Version', $ub, 'other');
        $pattern = '#(?<browser>' . join('|', $known) .
                ')[/ ]+(?<version>[0-9.|a-zA-Z.]*)#';
        if (!preg_match_all($pattern, $u_agent, $matches)) {
            // we have no matching number just continue
        }

        // see how many we have
        $i = count($matches['browser']);
        if ($i != 1) {
            //we will have two since we are not using 'other' argument yet
            //see if version is before or after the name
            if (strripos($u_agent, "Version") < strripos($u_agent, $ub)) {
                $version = $matches['version'][0];
            } else {
                $version = $matches['version'][1];
            }
        } else {
            $version = $matches['version'][0];
        }

        // check if we have a number
        if ($version == null || $version == "") {
            $version = "?";
        }

        return array(
            'userAgent' => $u_agent,
            'name' => $bname,
            'version' => $version,
            'platform' => $platform,
            'pattern' => $pattern
        );
    }
```

As found on the PHP reference for [get_browser()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php#101125)

Comment: Please supply us with the source of this codesnippet... Credit where credit is due!

Comment: @RichardBernards: Sure, but it have taken backup long ago. If I find that surely I'll add to my answer, don't worry :).